# BeautifulSoup.select Method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This script is suppose to take command line string and run it through the google search engine and then if results are found it will open up the first 5 in different tabs. I am having some issues trying to get it to work. I think the problem is happening towards the bottom where it says `link = soup.select(".r a")`, I have been altering the values here and then it will show the next line with an actual length. But running it like this shows the length to still be 0. I am trying to scrape the .r class and a tag because that seems to be where the searched results start on the google result source code.

```
import requests
import bs4
import sys
import webbrowser

print("Googling...")
response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + " ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
response.raise_for_status()

'''Function to return the top search result links'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

'''Open a browser tab for each result'''
links = soup.select(".r a")
print(len(links))
numOpen = min(5, len(links))

for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open("https://google.com/#q=" + links[i].get("href"))
```

Comment: This is because google is a javascript-heavy website. The HTML that you get in the `response` object contains almost nothing but javascript source links. The javascript must be fetched and executed before you can get any search results.

Comment: I would suggest you use a complete web crawler like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: @Abdelhakim Akodadi Google is a Javascript heavy website but I have noticed `response.text` has a full HTML with all the links. The logic is right, just the links are not right.

Comment: @Abdelhakim Akodadi I mean the URL for google search. It's gotta be `"https://www.google.com/search?q=" + " ".join(sys.argv[1:])` instead. Or it will not work when the Javascript is disabled. So the `requests.get` did not work.

Comment: @Eddie I see! My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is right except the URL for google search is not right.

It's gotta be

```
response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + " ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
...
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com" + links[i].get("href"))
```

**Here is the full code:**

```
import requests
import bs4
import sys
import webbrowser

print("Googling...")
response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + " ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
response.raise_for_status()

'''Function to return the top search result links'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

'''Open a browser tab for each result'''
links = soup.select(".r a")
print(len(links))
numOpen = min(5, len(links))

for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com" + links[i].get("href"))
```

Comment: Wow...that one little change in the reponse field fixed the entire thing :).

Answer (score 0):

You are right! The problem should be resulted from `select(".r a")`
I suggest you try `find_all('a',{"data-uch":1})`, which will find all a tags with attribute data-uch = 1

Explanation:

"If you look up a little from the  element, though, there is an element like this: . Looking through the rest of the HTML source,
it looks like the r class is used only for search result links."

The sentence above is from the book. However, in real, if you print this soup variable, `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")`, you will not find any ``` <h3 class="r">`` in the HTML source code. That is why ```print(len(links))``` always show 0.

Comment: sorry to see that you have not been active here for such a long time. I hope you will see my answer one day.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `min(5, len(links))` you can use slicing:

```py
links = soup.select('.r a')[:5]
# or 
for i in soup.select('.r a')[:5]:
    # other code..
```

Also, you can use [`find_all()` `limit` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#limit).

---

Make sure you're using `user-agent` because default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you'll receive a different HTML with some sort of an error. `User-agent` fakes user visit by adding this information into HTTP request headers.

I wrote a dedicated blog about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines that cover multiple solutions](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en",
  "num": "100"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc')[:5]:
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

  print(title, link, sep='\n')

--------
'''
Samurai Cop - He speaks fluent Japanese - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
Samurai Cop - What does "katana" mean? - Quotes.net
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
"It means "Japanese sword"... 2 minute review of a ... - Reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/47hw1g/what_does_katana_mean_it_means_japanese_sword_2/
Samurai Cop (1991) - Mathew Karedas as Joe Marshall - IMDb
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0130236/characters/nm0360481
What does Katana mean? - Samurai Cop quotes - Subzin.com
http://www.subzin.com/quotes/Samurai+Cop/What+does+Katana+mean%3F+-+It+means+Japanese+sword
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out how to pick the correct selector or how to bypass blocks from search engines since it's already done for the end-user. All that really needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"][:5]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])

---------
'''
Samurai Cop - He speaks fluent Japanese - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
Samurai Cop - What does "katana" mean? - Quotes.net
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
"It means "Japanese sword"... 2 minute review of a ... - Reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/47hw1g/what_does_katana_mean_it_means_japanese_sword_2/
Samurai Cop (1991) - Mathew Karedas as Joe Marshall - IMDb
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0130236/characters/nm0360481
What does Katana mean? - Samurai Cop quotes - Subzin.com
http://www.subzin.com/quotes/Samurai+Cop/What+does+Katana+mean%3F+-+It+means+Japanese+sword
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.